# VW MQ200 Gear Selector Shaft Bolt/Nut is Snapped, does the whole gearbox need to be replaced?

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, gears, skoda, bolts

The Gearbox is a Volkswagon MQ200 series installed on a Skoda Octavia 2008. I experienced problem with the reverse and 5th gear engagement, so attempted to fix the problem.

While tightening the nut/bolt (marked in red circle) to tightly connect the "Gear shift lever" on the "selector shaft", the nut/bolt has broken off or snapped. I am not sure whether the snapped part is a nut or a bolt. If it is a bolt then it should be possible to extract the broken bolt with a bolt extractor.

But based on the following picture, it seems, what is broken/snapped is a nut together with the extended portion of the bolt as marked in the blue circle in the bottom picture.

Do I need to change the whole gearbox due to this broken nut or bolt?
Somebody suggested trying to fix the connection by welding. Would this be a good idea?

[image: While tightening the bolt (marked in red circle) to connect the Gear shift lever on the selector shaft, the bolt has off or snapped.]

[image: The highlighted area in the blue circle shows the selector shaft. I assume the bolt/nut was attached in this place]

Comment: a picture of the actual broken part would be helpful

Comment: You could drill into the shaft and tap some threads into it and then put a stud into it.